# Set up sftp to use password but ssh not to use password

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, ssh

Is it possible to set up a user on ubuntu with openssh so that ssh does not use password authentication but sftp does?

I assume that if I change `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to have `PasswordAuthentication yes` this makes is possible for users to use passwords to login with both ssh and sftp.

Edit: My purpose here is to let some users sftp with a password instead of a keyfile.  But I do not want ssh users to be able to login with a password, I want them to have to use a keyfile.  If it helps, I do not need the sftp users to be able to login, they only need to do sftp.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As I understand you have (at least for this particular problem) two **distinct** groups of users, one being able to login via SSH and get an interactive shell (let's call the group `ssh`) and one being able to login via SFTP and only get an SFTP shell (let's call the group `sftp`).

Now create the groups `ssh` and `sftp` on your system with `groupadd`, put the respective users in the groups (`gpasswd -a $USERNAME $GROUPNAME`) and append the following lines at the end (*this is important!*) of your `sshd_config` located at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match Group sftp
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  # Further directives for users in the "sftp" group

Match Group ssh
  PasswordAuthentication no
  # Further directives for users in the "ssh" group
```

Read about the `Match` directive in [sshd_config(5)](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5) and about the allowed *patterns* in [ssh_config(5)](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#PATTERNS).

You'll also have to restart the `ssh` process for this to take effect:

`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Comment: This isn't well documented, but only one Match directive will be used; you should put the most specific directive on top. If you list sftp first, a user who is in both groups will be allowed PasswordAuthentication.

Comment: Thanks!  There's already a `ssh` group on my ubuntu boxes, so I really only need to add `sftp` and put the sftp users into that group.  I'll combine your answer with using `scponly` to keep the sftp users from logging in.

Comment: If `PasswordAuthentication` is set to `no` further up, will this still work? Does `Match Group` override it for sftp users? Because that's what I have and it doesn't work. I can ssh in with key, but can't as an sftp user.

Answer (score 0):

No, and I don't see how this would improve security, so what would be the point?

[authorized_keys](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/sshd.8.html#toptoc6) can allow different commands for different keys, if that's what you're after. Otherwise, you have the option of creating several accounts and using acls or sudo.

Comment: I'm not trying to improve security.  I'm trying to make it easier for some users to use a password instead of a keyfile for sftp access.  However, I do not want anyone to use a password for ssh access.

Comment: @dar OK; different accounts then. If they were the same account, someone knowing the sftp password could overwrite some profile file (.ssh/rc, .profile, .bashrc…) and get the same privileges as someone knowing the private key.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab in the dark here, but you may find this thread interesting.

[It is fair to jail my SFTP users to their home directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/41212/it-is-fair-to-jail-my-sftp-users-to-their-home-directory)

Comment: I don't see anything in there about PasswordAuthentication, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, you're correct.  It wasn't clear what you wanted to do with SFTP vs SSH.  I see from the other comment that you want users to use a password for SFTP but not for SSH.  Why?

Comment: Because these users that need to use sftp find keyfiles challenging, but they understand how to type in passwords.  It boils down to a user experience issue for sftp.  But I want to minimize the attack surface area by keeping passwords out of the ssh mix.

Comment: SFTP works by first opening a ssh tunnel, then transmitting files via FTP.  You can't really divorce the two.  I guess you could by setting up some ACLs, but that doesn't really make sense.